# Column with column names?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I need to make a column referencing other column by name. Specifically, my intended use case is to create a list of required columns. This can't be achieved by setting a `required` boolean or something like that since the required columns vary by row.
Ex:

```
Table 1
| id | value_1 | value_2 | value_3 |
|----------------------------------|

Table 2
| id | some_data |    required_columns    |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 1  |    ...    | ['value_1', 'value_2'] |
| 2  |    ...    | ['value_1', 'value_3'] |
| 3  |    ...    | ['value_2', 'value_3'] |
```

I've been searching around, but haven't found a way to meta-reference a column other than by name. This worries me, since it's usual for column names to change. Is there a better way to achieve this, other than storing the column names as strings?

Comment: Is it fair to say that you are looking for a web a desktop UI to call the database and ask which field is required and which is optional? If that is what you are hoping to do, build the logic in the application layer that feeds the UI.

Comment: The problem is that those required fields are constantly changing, and new are also added. Building the logic at the application level would be counter-productive

Comment: Moving between data & column names is "pivoting". Also research problems with anti-pattern "EAV".

Comment: The required_fields column is not meant to be searched. It serves as a reference between separate services. The idea is to be decoupled from what a column is named on the separate service, but reference that same column uniquely